# Bash script - Maintain multiple instances running

Tags: bash, shell

How can I ensure, that **multiple** instances of certain program are always running?

Let's say that I want to make sure that 4 instances of a certain program are always running.
If one instance is killed, new one should start.
If 5 instances are running, one should be killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a shell question, because the approach is the same, whichever shell you are using.

I think the cleanest solution is to have a "watchdog", which checks the running processes (using `ps`) and, if necessary, starts a new one or kills an unnecessary one.

One way - which I have used in a similar situation - is to write a cron job, which regularly (say: every 5 minutes) starts the watchdog and let it do his work.

If such an interval is too long for your case (i.e. if you need checking it more often than every minute), you could have the watchdog run continuously, in a loop. Still, you will need a cron job, which controls in turn the watchdog from time to time - just in case the watchdogs dies. In this case you might consider running it as a [daemon](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html).